# how to get specific country time zone using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to get abbreviations of timezones with Moment.js.

still i am not getting the output

Moment.js provides https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/getting-country-zones/

```
moment.tz.zonesForCountry('US')
```

which gives list of array( timezones of USA)

```
["America/Adak", "America/Anchorage", "America/Boise", "America/Chicago", "America/Denver", "America/Detroit", "America/Indiana/Indianapolis", "America/Indiana/Knox", "America/Indiana/Marengo", "America/Indiana/Petersburg", "America/Indiana/Tell_City", "America/Indiana/Vevay", "America/Indiana/Vincennes", "America/Indiana/Winamac", "America/Juneau", "America/Kentucky/Louisville", "America/Kentucky/Monticello", "America/Los_Angeles", "America/Menominee", "America/Metlakatla", "America/New_York", "America/Nome", "America/North_Dakota/Beulah", "America/North_Dakota/Center", "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem", "America/Phoenix", "America/Sitka", "America/Yakutat", "Pacific/Honolulu"]
```

For abbreviations which i tried

```
let abbr = moment.tz.zonesForCountry('US').map((z) =>moment.tz(z).zoneAbbr());
```

output/required output

```
["HDT", "AKDT", "MDT", "CDT", "MDT", "EDT", "EDT", "CDT", "EDT", "EDT", "CDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "AKDT", "EDT", "EDT", "PDT", "CDT", "AKDT", "EDT", "AKDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "MST", "AKDT", "AKDT", "HST"]
```

tried using

```
 mtz.tz.zonesOfCountry('US').map((listzones) =>mtz.tz(listzones).zoneAbbr())

getting "undefined"
```

If you have any suggestion let me know.

Comment: What is the outcome you are looking for? using ```let abbr = moment.tz.zonesForCountry('US').map((z) =>moment.tz(z).zoneAbbr());``` returns ```["HDT", "AKDT", "MDT", "CDT", "MDT", "EDT", "EDT", "CDT", "EDT", "EDT", "CDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "AKDT", "EDT", "EDT", "PDT", "CDT", "AKDT", "EDT", "AKDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "MST", "AKDT", "AKDT", "HST"]``` which seems like the desired behavior

Comment: What is the issue here exactly?

Comment: @GrantSingleton  required output ["HDT", "AKDT", "MDT", "CDT", "MDT", "EDT", "EDT", "CDT", "EDT", "EDT", "CDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "AKDT", "EDT", "EDT", "PDT", "CDT", "AKDT", "EDT", "AKDT", "CDT", "CDT", "CDT", "MST", "AKDT", "AKDT", "HST"]  i am not getting after using let abbr = moment.tz.zonesForCountry('US').map((z) =>moment.tz(z).zoneAbbr())

Comment: this code is not working for me , do we any solution to get abbreviations

Comment: I ran it on my end and it works as expected. What error or output are you getting when logging ```abbr``` to the console?

Comment: it is showing undefined....actually i tried like this as well
mtz.tz.zonesOfCountry('US').map((listzones) =>mtz.tz(listzones).zoneAbbr())

Comment: What is ```mtz``` here? did you import moment as mtz?

Comment: Yes I have imported and I am using for other scenarios as well

Comment: I am sorry I wish I could help more. The code you posted works fine for me. There must be something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for you reply ,do we have any other method to get abbreviations??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214848/discussion-between-grant-singleton-and-user13465472).

Answer (score 0):

var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.